# Poner imágenes a botones en un Alert (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

El tema es que, quiero tratar de usar 5 imágenes de una estrella como 5 botones a modo de valoración al salir de la aplicación que he creado en `JavaFX` mediante `SceneBuilder`.

He asociado un método **apagarPrograma()** a un botón que cierra el programa, pero antes te muestra un `Alert.CONFIRMATION` (el cuál permite añadir tantos ButtonType como quieras).

El problema es que ha diferencia de `swing`, no existe un método setIcon para los `ButtonType`.

He probado con el uso de Button, pero este aunque cuenta con el método setBackground(), no me permite asociarlo al alert mediante alert.getButtonTypes.setAll(boton1, boton2....) debido a que este método solo añade ButtonType a el ObservableList.

Quisiera saber como proceder, si debo cambiar el tipo de `Alert`, hacerlo de otra manera, o existe algún método para asignar la imagen al botón y este a un diálogo , Gracias.

Adjunto el código del método por si fuera de utilidad para comprender la pregunta:

```
@FXML
public void apagarPrograma() { // botón para apagar el programa

    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setHeaderText("ADIÓS!!");

    ButtonType oneStar = new ButtonType("");
    ButtonType twoStars = new ButtonType("");
    ButtonType threeStars = new ButtonType("");
    ButtonType fourStars = new ButtonType("");
    ButtonType fiveStars = new ButtonType("");

    oneStar.??
    twoStar.??

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque no pruebas usando un [rating bar](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#rating). Como indica su [documentación](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/Rating.html) ya pone automáticamente la estrellas y no tienes que usar imágenes.